# Need help to reduce a code (i'm not an expert)

Tags: javascript

I am creating a condition to display a few div and hide others at the launch of a function. This is the code I opted for, would it be possible to reduce it?

```
if (select.value=="v-smartphones-modele-samsungs6"){
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-apple').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsung').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-grade-samsung').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('div-tablettes').style.display = "none";
          
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs6-capacite').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs6edge-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs6edgeplus-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs7-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs7edge-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs8-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs8plus-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs9-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs9plus-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs10-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs10plus-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs10e-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs20-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs20plus-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs20ultra5g-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs20fe-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsunggalaxyfold-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsunggalaxyzflip-capacite').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsunggalaxyzfold2-capacite').style.display = "none";
         
         
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs6').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs6edge').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs6edgeplus').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs7').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs7edge').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs8').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs8plus').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs9').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs9plus').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs10').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs10plus').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs10e').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs20').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs20plus').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs20ultra5g').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsungs20fe').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsunggalaxyfold').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsunggalaxyzflip').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-grade-samsunggalaxyzfold2').style.display = "none";
         
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs6').style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs6edge').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs6edgeplus').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs7').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs7edge').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs8').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs8plus').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs9').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs9plus').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs10').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs10plus').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs10e').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs20').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs20plus').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs20ultra5g').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsungs20fe').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsunggalaxyfold').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsunggalaxyzflip').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('div-smartphone-result-samsunggalaxyzfold2').style.display = "none";

          
         }
```

Comment: We'd need to see a [mcve], but this appears to be a good example of why you want to use CSS classes

Comment: Can you give some context as to what you're trying to implement here? It would also help if you include the relevant part of your HTML.

Comment: It appears you are doing the same thing with many objects. What you should do is regroup those things in classes and also give them a separated ID, so you can change them together by using a class or change a single object by using its ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want change HTML structure by grouping with classes you can do a lot with [CSS [attribute^=value] Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) and  [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) JS selector.

**Example** using `div-smartphone-` part of `id`, and excluding some:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="div-smartphone-"]:not(#div-smartphone-result-apple)').forEach(el => {
  el.style.color = "red";
})
```

```html
<div id="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs6edge-capacite">div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs6edge-capacite</div>
<div id="div-smartphone-result-samsung">div-smartphone-result-samsung</div>
<div id="div-smartphone-marque">div-smartphone-marque</div>
<div id="div-smartphone-marque-samsung">div-smartphone-marque-samsung</div>
<div id="div-smartphone-grade-samsung">div-smartphone-grade-samsung</div>
<div id="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs6edge-capacite">div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-samsungs6edge-capacite</div>
<div id="div-smartphone-result-apple">div-smartphone-result-apple</div>
```

This way your code can be summed in couple of lines.

**EDIT:**

To answer question in comment.
Yes, you can do all kind of combinations, please read: [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for full list of selector, and you can use all in `queryselector`, and combinations of it.

**Example**

```
querySelectorAll('div[id^="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-"][id$="-capacite"]:not([id*="SAMSUNGMODEL1"])')
```

Code above does next:

- `div[id^="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-"]` this part takes all elements that id starts with: `div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-`
- [`id$="-capacite"]` this part takes all that ends with `-capacite`
- `:not([id*="SAMSUNGMODEL1"]` this part excludes ids that contains `SAMSUNGMODEL1`

So all of those 3 together give you filter that you need:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-"][id$="-capacite"]:not([id*="SAMSUNGMODEL1"])').forEach(el => {
  el.style.color = "red";
})
```

```html
<div id="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-nokia-capacite">div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-nokia-capacite</div>
<div id="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-apple-capacite">div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-apple-capacite</div>
<div id="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-SAMSUNGMODEL1-capacite">div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-SAMSUNGMODEL1-capacite  *has SAMSUNGMODEL1</div>
<div id="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-sonny-capacite">div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-sonny-capacite</div>
<div id="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-SAMSUNGMODEL1">div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-SAMSUNGMODEL1 *missing -capacite</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! 
I also have a large div group in which there is a change in the middle of the nomenclature, is it also possible to use the queryselector ? 

For example :

document.getElementById('div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-SAMSUNGMODEL1-capacite').style.display = "block";

is it possible to put "display:none" to all div different from div with SAMSUNGMODEL1 in the middle of the nomenclature?

Comment: Hello and sorry to disturb you again :P 
I tried your solution but i don't know why, it doesn’t work for me, I don’t understand what I’m doing wrong.
Do you see an error in that code?

document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="div-smartphone-marque-samsung-modele-"][id$="-capacite"]:not([id*="samsungs6"])').forEach(el => {
      el.style.display = "none";})

Thanks again for your time

Comment: No, its working: https://jsfiddle.net/et8bx4gs/ , check your console.log for possible errors. Make sure you are including this properly, at end of document (would be good to wrap it up in document ready to load when DOM is ready). Also if this content is added dynamically, you need to reapply the filter in order to make it work. @cardt18

Comment: Thank i will check, but it's maybe too complicated for my level. 
If i add the same class to all my divs, do you know if it's possible to do something like this ?
Running the function : Hide all the divs where class=("classname") & where the id is not "samsungs6" ?

Comment: @cardt18 Its  same thing as code above. If you do not know how to add to your site code above you wont be able to make it work with the way you are mentioning. You are doing something wrong with implementation. Cant guide you with that, read the basics of java-script... Sorry. This works, as you can see in snippets.

Comment: Heyyy my bad, i checked again and it's working perfectly !! thank you so much you really helped me :P

Comment: @cardt18 Great, and np. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 2):

If you have created those `id` in your HTML, you should give them a `class`, and then on your JavaScript, you can `document.getElementByClassName` and set all their style to block

**French** :

Salut, je vois que tu es Fr ^^
Deja bienvenu à toi,

Si t'as avez créé ces `id` dans ton HTML, tu dois leur donner une  `classe`, puis sur ton JavaScript, tu peux `document.getElementByClassName` et définir tous leurs style.

Comment: Salut Bob et merci pour ta réponse ! Je suis plutôt en train d'essayer le Query selector qui me paraît plus simple. Sais-tu s'il est possible d'utiliser le Query Selector pour selectionner toutes les divs ayant un ID commençant par  "div-smartphone-" et terminant par "capacite" ? Je ne sais pas si c'est possible de l'utiliser pour chercher entre un début et une fin de ID (comme le changement est en milieu d'ID)